# How to get Jquery parentsUntil() to remove whole HTML block

Tags: jquery, html

I have some jquery i want to use to create form elements dynamically and I can add whole new form elements but I have a problem with removing them.

I am trying to remove an entire block of HTML but instead of removing the block I want removed, it removes all HTML right up to the  tag

I can add as many form elements (in div groups) as I like and I can remove them singally until it gets to the last one then it removes the group i added plus the static html in the page which i don't want removed.

I think it's to do with parentsUntil() but don't know another way of removing all the HTML in that code block.

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="adminForm" action="" method="post">
    <div class="group" id="fixed">
        <p class="hint">Please enter a welcome message for the newsletter.</p>
        <label class="formlabel" for="welcome">WELCOME MESSAGElabel><br />
        <input type="text" class="text-input" name="welcome" id="welcome" />
    </div>
    <p><span id="addVar">Add Variable</span></p>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var startingNo = 0;
var $node = "";
for(varCount=0;varCount<=startingNo;varCount++){
    var displayCount = varCount+1;

    $node = "<div class=\"article\">\n\t<div class=\"group\">\n\t\t<p class=\"hint\">Please enter a title for article "+displayCount+".</p>\n\t\t<label class=\"formlabel\" for=\"article_title"+displayCount+"\">ARTICLE TITLE "+displayCount+"</label><br />\n\t\t<input type=\"text\" name=\"article_title"+displayCount+"\" id=\"article_title"+displayCount+"\" class=\"text-input\" />\n\t</div>\n\t<div class=\"group\">\n\t\t<p class=\"hint\">Please enter the content for article "+displayCount+".</p>\n\t\t<label class=\"formlabel\" for=\"article_content"+displayCount+"\">ARTICLE CONTENT "+displayCount+"</label><br />\n\t\t<textarea rows=\"10\" cols=\"50\" class=\"text-input\" name=\"article_content"+displayCount+"\" id=\"article_content"+displayCount+"\"></textarea>\n\t</div>\n\t<div class=\"group\">\n\t\t<span class=\"removeVar\">Remove Article</span>\n\t</div>\n</div>";
}
$('#fixed').append($node);

$('#adminForm').on('click', '.removeVar', function(){
    $(this).parentsUntil($('#adminForm')).remove();
    //varCount--;
});

$('#addVar').on('click', function(){
    //new node
    varCount++;

    $node = "<div class=\"article\">\n\t<div class=\"group\">\n\t\t<p class=\"hint\">Please enter a title for article "+varCount+".</p>\n\t\t<label class=\"formlabel\" for=\"article_title"+varCount+"\">ARTICLE TITLE "+varCount+"</label><br />\n\t\t<input type=\"text\" name=\"article_title"+varCount+"\" id=\"article_title"+varCount+"\" class=\"text-input\" />\n\t</div>\n\t<div class=\"group\">\n\t\t<p class=\"hint\">Please enter the content for article "+varCount+".</p>\n\t\t<label class=\"formlabel\" for=\"article_content"+varCount+"\">ARTICLE CONTENT "+varCount+"</label><br />\n\t\t<textarea rows=\"10\" cols=\"50\" class=\"text-input\" name=\"article_content"+varCount+"\" id=\"article_content"+varCount+"\"></textarea>\n\t</div>\n\t<div class=\"group\">\n\t\t<span class=\"removeVar\">Remove Article</span>\n\t</div>\n</div>";

    $(this).parent().before($node);
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding what the problem is, your code appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/sycuC/

Comment: If the problem is that it is removing the `#fixed` div as well, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/JJvqN/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter out the `#fixed` div by using `.not()`

```
$('#adminForm').on('click', '.removeVar', function () {
    $(this).parentsUntil($('#adminForm')).not('#fixed').remove();
    //varCount--;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it still deletes them all

Comment: What do you mean it deleted them all?

Comment: It deleted the div group id'd #fixed

Comment: I don't understand becuase your fiddle works fine and I can see that but when i out it in the site i@m developing, it deletes the whole form

Comment: Yes it is.  I found another way of doing it (not as good but at least it doesn't delete the whole form